# subfolder url get parameter not working in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a website like www.abc.com/service/page.php?ids=social. I redirected site to www.abc.com/service/social. But i need to avoid this folder from url.Ex:www.abc.com/social.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /service/
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+|)/?$ page.php?ids=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply exclude "service" from the regex match:

```
RewriteRule ^service/([a-zA-Z0-9]+|)/?$ page.php?ids=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in site root .htaccess (i.e. parent directory of `/service/`):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^service/ service%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: its not redirecting.

Comment: It is not supposed to redirect, it just rewrites. Where is this .htaccess located and what is error when you enter `www.abc.com/social` in browser?